# Perform a calculation at every latitude-longitude point

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray data array, `mx2t`, which contains hourly temperatures over a region. What I am trying to do is find the maximum temperature in the data for each latitude-longitude point and then plot it on a map.

Running  `mx2t.max()` will give me the largest value in the entire array, but how do I get the largest value for each latitude-longitude point?

This is what my coordinates look like in the data array:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [xarary docs on aggregation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#aggregation).

The [`DataArray.max`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.max.html#xarray.DataArray.max) API accepts a `dim` argument, which acts similarly to numpy's `axis` argument (except it accepts a dimension name rather than positional index):

```py
mx2t.max(dim='time')
```

will take the max over the time dimension, returning a `(latitude, longitude)` DataArray with the point-wise max.

You can also provide multiple dimensions to any of the aggregation functions; in your example, to create a time series of the max over both latitude and longitude:

```py
mx2t.max(dim=('latitude', 'longitude'))
```